# How do I make Thibbledorf Pwent, Most Wild Battlerager?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, armor, unarmed-combat

I have searched for this, but only found a 4th ed D&D topic, I require a 5th ed character.

[Thibbledorf Pwent](http://annex.wikia.com/wiki/Thibbledorf_Pwent)

> … is a dwarven Battlerager (the Most Wild Battlerager as he has called himself), a type of warrior characterized by their unorthodox style of fighting. He wears armor with many incredibly sharp ridges and set—at his knuckles, elbows, knees, and toes—with hooked spikes, which he uses to tear his opponents to shreds by wrapping them in a bear hug and flailing about until his victim goes limp, often continuing to mutilate corpses of his victims out of sheer blood lust.

How do I make this character in 5th ed? I'm thinking it's not really possible to achieve the basics until 4th level.

Requirements - needs to be a dwarf, weapons need to be unarmed and his armour.

Comment: When asking for character build advice like this, it's very helpful to include as much of the character build as you already have in the question.  You say it's "possible to achieve the basics [at] 4th level", which implies that you already have some idea of how to do this.  Rather than asking for a full build, show us what build you already have, and tell us what part of it you're not satisfied with.  If you don't know how to make spiked armor, or you want to make it work from level 1, or whatever else your current build doesn't allow, we can help with that once you've narrowed it down.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the Battlerager Primal Path from Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide. It's based on exactly this, and includes spiked armor and damaging grapples.